# How to select 2 boolean columns and retrieve 1 boolean result (both must be true = true)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server I have multiple `bit` columns. If either the product = False or the Category = False, I want to return False.

My test code:

```
declare @b0 bit
declare @b1 bit

set @b0 = 0
set @b1 = 1

select (@b0 and @b1)
select (@b0 + @b1)
select (@b0 = @b1)
```

But all 3 selects crash.

My actual code snippet:

```
select 
    c.bCatActive,    -- I want to dispose of this line.
    p.bProdActive,   -- I want to dispose of this line.
    (c.bCatActive and p.bProdActive) as IsActive  -- I want to retrieve this line but doesn't work.
from 
    Category c, Product p
where 
    p.ProductID = 999
    and c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
```

Of course I can do this with two If-Thens but my current query is pleasantly one clean query so I was hoping to do this in one neat line.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Curious: if the two fields are together effectively defining four separate states, then they are probably better as a single `tinyint` or `char` with a check constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close, booleans should use boolean logic:

```
declare @b0 bit
declare @b1 bit

set @b0 = 0
set @b1 = 0

select (@b0 & @b1)
```

Use **&** for and, **|** for or

Comment: Thank you!  I was truly just that close.

Comment: "Booleans should use boolean logic" `and` is boolean logic, but `bit` is not boolean, it is a 1-bit integer. `&` is bit manipulation, which you do with integers. So more correctly "`bit` is an integer, and should use bit manipulation."

Answer (score 1):

How about explicit comparisons?

```
(case when c.bCatActive = 1 and p.bProdActive = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as IsActive
```

`bits` are not *booleans*.

You should also learn proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If those are just 0 and 1 then try this:

```
select (c.bCatActive * p.bProdActive) as IsActive  
from Category c
   , Product p
where p.ProductID = 999
  and c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
```

It will only produce 1 as IsActive if both c.bCatActive  and p.bProdActive have the value 1. If any of those is 0 the it will return 0. It's the only option I could think of right now since you dont want to use if or case.

Comment: Can any of those fields be null?